# shortcode displays at wrong place, always on the top

Tags: php, position, return, shortcode, ob-start

Iam working on a webshop thats going to display the cart before the checkout. like now it is the checkout before the cart.

I cant get this to work.
I got a problem that the plugin always shows on the top of the content.
i fixed this a wihle ago. Now i updated the plugin and tryed same thing agien as you can read at the buttom hear.

The code is original like this:

```
public function __construct() {

    add_action('init', array( &$this, 'start_session' ), 1);

    add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_klarna_checkout', array(&$this, 'klarna_checkout_page') );

    //add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( &$this, 'checkout_button' ), 12 );

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', array( &$this, 'change_checkout_url' ), 20 );



}

// Set session
function start_session() {      

    $data = new WC_Gateway_Klarna_Checkout;
    $enabled = $data->get_enabled();

    if(!session_id() && $enabled == 'yes') {
        session_start();
    }
}

// Shortcode
function klarna_checkout_page() {

    $data = new WC_Gateway_Klarna_Checkout;
    $data->get_klarna_checkout_page();


    }
```

and i have tryed this:

```
            ob_start();
    $data->get_klarna_checkout_page();
    $output_string=ob_get_contents();;
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output_string;
```

Than the hole plugin dispear and only thing that shows is /*

As i wrote at the top this solution worked on an erlier version of the plugin but not now.
And all i can find at the webb is this solution. So if anyone have any idea i would love it.

Mabey the problem is that the shortcode isnt in the funktion where i put ob_start(); ?
Iam like a newbie on php and cant seems to get this to work by my self.

Comment: The shortcode function doesn't return anything?

Comment: as i wrote in the post iam kind of new whit php. what should i return to then?

Comment: like a said aim not that good on php, but as i see it i do return it whit this: $output_string=ob_get_contents();; and later on this: return $output_string; Im i right ? also tried whit only one ; does not make any diffrent.